# REACT TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to build a static web page to practice.
When I try to open the web page I get this error referring to the App.js file in src folder.

[Error1-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epPU2.png)

App.js code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import Task from './task.js'
import Navbar from './js/Navbar';
import MainPage from './js/MainPage';
import './App.css';

const tasks = [];
tasks.push(new Task("finish lab07", 0, 1, "AWI", "2020-05-27", 0));
tasks.push(new Task("finish ", 1, 1, "AWI", "2020/05/30", 0));
tasks.push(new Task("start studyng", 0, 1, "FL", "2020/06/01", 0));

const projects = [{id: 0, projectName: "AWI"}, {id: 1, projectName: "FL"}];

class App extends React.Component() {
     constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {tasks: tasks};
     }

     render(){
          return (
               <>
                  <Navbar id="navbar" />
                  <MainPage projects={projects} tasks={tasks}/>
               </>
          );
     } 
}

export default App;
```

If I try to import React, {Component} from 'react'
and I use "extends Component" instead of "extends React.Component" I get this error:

[Error2-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8WhP.png)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It should be `class App extends React.Component` instead of `class App extends React.Component()`. Remove `()`

Comment: can you remove parenthesis () after React.component?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should do:

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
    }
}
```

You are calling the `Component` with `Component()` class which is why it is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

you are extending `React.Component()` not `React.Component`

see the working code below

```
import React from 'react';
import Task from './task.js'
import Navbar from './js/Navbar';
import MainPage from './js/MainPage';
import './App.css';

const tasks = [];
tasks.push(new Task("finish lab07", 0, 1, "AWI", "2020-05-27", 0));
tasks.push(new Task("finish ", 1, 1, "AWI", "2020/05/30", 0));
tasks.push(new Task("start studyng", 0, 1, "FL", "2020/06/01", 0));

const projects = [{id: 0, projectName: "AWI"}, {id: 1, projectName: "FL"}];

class App extends React.Component {
     constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {tasks: tasks};
     }

     render(){
          return (
               <>
                  <Navbar id="navbar" />
                  <MainPage projects={projects} tasks={tasks}/>
               </>
          );
     } 
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Oh my god. I don't even know how those round brackets are there. I've used "npx create-react-app" to initialize the project. And I didn't notice. Useless topic here ahahah. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is you need to do `Component` not `Component()`

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'; // import Component
import Task from './task.js'
import Navbar from './js/Navbar';
import MainPage from './js/MainPage';
import './App.css';

const tasks = [];
tasks.push(new Task("finish lab07", 0, 1, "AWI", "2020-05-27", 0));
tasks.push(new Task("finish ", 1, 1, "AWI", "2020/05/30", 0));
tasks.push(new Task("start studyng", 0, 1, "FL", "2020/06/01", 0));

const projects = [{id: 0, projectName: "AWI"}, {id: 1, projectName: "FL"}];
// Extends Component (not Component())
class App extends Component {
     constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {tasks: tasks};
     }

     render(){
          return (
               <>
                  <Navbar id="navbar" />
                  <MainPage projects={projects} tasks={tasks}/>
               </>
          );
     } 
}

export default App;
```